# How to detect URL changes in UmiJS React Web application?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, umijs

There is `BasicLayout.jsx` in my application which pass down the props for main components and render the child components inside the layout. I want to perform some logic depends on URL changes inside the `useEffect()` of `BasicLayout.jsx`. Is there any efficient way to detect any URL changes with `useLocation` hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case that I want to re-render the `BasicLayout.tsx`, I used `useHistoy()` hook instead of `useLocation()` and passed the current URL pathname as dependency to the `useEffect()`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

  let url = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
     ...
     // perform some logic
     ...
  }, [currentUser, declaration, url.location.pathname]);
```